# C++ prototypes not being redefined

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in programming and am just starting to write programs that are complex enough where prototypes would be helpful. The problem is when I write my program, compile and run it the functions that are prototyped are blank so none of my cout or cin 
prompts in the later defined functions appear.

In this code there is only one portion of the switch statement done in which the CubeVol function is prototyped and then later defined.

This code does compile and when it is run it shows the menu. When I type "2" the program ends without couting "length of cubes side" or asking for an input.

if it matters, I'm using Cygwin with gnu g++ compiler and notepad++ to write the code, which is saved as a .C file. I've also tried formatting it as a .cpp

Keep in mind that the mostly blank switch statement is for later when I actually finish the program.

***how do i prototype the CubeVol Function Correctly?***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double CubeVol();


int main()
{ int choice=0; 
cout<< " 1. Sphere \n 2. Cube \n 3. Cone \n 4. Cylinder \n 5. Prism \n 6. Exit \n";
cin>> choice;

switch (choice){
    case 1:
    ;
    break;
    case 2:
     CubeVol;
    break;
    case 3:
    ;
    break;
    case 4:
    ;
    break;
    case 5:
    ;
    break ;
    case 6:
    ;
    ;
    break;
    };

}  

    double CubeVol ()
{ 
double side=0.0; double cubev=0.0;
  cout<< "length of cubes side";
  cin>> side;
  cubev= pow(side,3);
return cubev;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it has anything to do with prototypes, and what do you mean "prototypes not being redefined"? Regardless, see @Kunal's answer and fix your `case 2:` block.

Comment: i very new to programing so to my inexperienced eyes it seemes to be that the prototpye not being defined as the CubeVol function

Comment: "Not being defined" is certainly significantly different than the "not being redefined" you put in your title ;)  Most of the time, in C++ if you have not included a prototype your compiler will terminate with an error. The one case I can think of where this might not happen is if you've got overloaded functions where one can be promoted to the other and you provided one prototype but intended to call the other. (Sorry if that sounds complicated -- it's certainly esoteric.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function `CubeVol()` in `case 2:`

```
case 2:
   std::cout << CubeVol() << "\n"; //call the function and print return value
break;
```

Also the return value is not being utilized.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the return statement back in. i removed in a worthless attempt to get the prototype to work

Comment: thanks that worked every time i have an error it something simple like this. like when i just started using notepad++ i was trying to compile .h header files by themselves and could not figure out why i was getting a path error when i tried running the program . after about 5 hours of trying to fix it i gave up for the night, only to have my professor the next day fix it on the first try by saving it as a .C file

Comment: and a quick question in your fix you have "std::cout" that defines that it will use the standard namespace. But since i have using namespace std at the top of my program i don't need that right?

Comment: Yes, you don't need that but avoid `using namespace std;`. Its not a good practice and will lead to problems in a bigger codebase.